# Как занять блоком всё свободное место?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

что бы блок "w" заполнял всё свободное место справа от блока "q". Ширина блока "w" всегда разная.

```css
.q {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: RED;
  float: left;
}
.w {
  float: left;
  background-color: GREEN;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="q"></div>
  <div class="w">
    TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мы вроде в 2018 году, а в ответах флоаты и таблицы. Не пойдет так. Решение на flexbox

```css
.c {
  display:flex;
  height: 100px;
}
.q {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: RED;
}
.w {
  background-color: GREEN;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <div class="q"></div>
  <div class="w">
    TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: пффф решил выпендрится) вот тебе ответ чем таблицы лучше https://i.stack.imgur.com/azmua.png думаешь не найти людей которые пользуются устаревшими браузерами, да таких полно

Answer (score 0):

Вот так)

```css
.block {
    display: table;
}
.q {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: RED;
    display: table-cell;
}
.w {
    background-color: GREEN;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="q"></div>
  <div class="w">
    TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .q {
      width: 500px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: RED;
      float: left;
    }
    .w {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: GREEN;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
      <div class="q"></div>
      <div class="w">
        TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
      </div>
    </div>
```